# Обработка падения дочернего процесса в Qt

Tags: windows, qt, c++, процесс

Здравствуйте! Я с помощью класса QProcess создаю дочерний процесс. Если этот процесс из-за какой-либо ошибки падает, то я должен это соответствующим образом обработать. Собственно вопрос: можно ли сделать так, чтобы при падении дочернего процесса в Windows не вылетало окно "Прекращена работа программы ... . Windows может провести поиск способа устранения этой ошибки в Интернете"? Проблема в том, что дочерних процессов может быть много, а эти сообщения никому не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть лучше поработать над логикой процессов, что бы они не прекращались системой насильно? Тем более если вы работаете в Qt, там работа с процессами и с потоками очень просто реализована.

Так же можно запускать ни несколько процессов, а несколько потоков. Если вы не работаете с большими объемами памяти, то в зависимости от количества ядер и наличия/отсутствия гиперпоточности процессора, достаточно по одному процессу на каждое физическое/логическое ядро и там уже можно работать с потоками, которые будут обваливаться и запускаться заново, без особых проблем.

И да, в Windows нет ни дочерних ни родительских процессов, в отличие от Unix, в Windows все процессы равнозначны, так что это абстракция Qt.

Comment: Ukeo, спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, но то, что Вы предложили, мне не подходит. Дело в том, что я пишу систему тестирования программ по стратегии чёрного ящика, т.е. мне надо тестировать программы, исходного кода которых у меня нет. Самый простой вид теста - сгенерировать по шаблону входные данные, запустить процесс и проверить, что всё корректно отработало.

Comment: Ну, это чисто системный механизм, процессор выполняет прерывание, его перехватывает ядро и потом вверх по цепочке, до пользователя. Сам процесс тут уже не участвует, он просто завершается. 

При условии, что ни каких исходников нет нужно как-то исхитрятся. Посмотрите Win32 API, и разработку с его помощью. Если вы в любом случае работаете в Windows и нет нужды в кроссплатформенности, это даст вам больше инструментов.

P.S.
Хотя может и есть какой-нибудь просто способ, я не знаю.